The definition of Science Fiction and Fantasy in the FAQ
I saw the following comment on a recently closed question:

This question doesn't appears to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy, as defined in the FAQ.

The story, as described in the question, sounds rather mundane. My question is about the part of the comment that I emphasized.
Are Science Fiction and Fantasy really defined in the FAQ? If so where? If not, why do people say that it is?

I interpret this a little different, the on-topic specifies that the SITE is for SF&F questions and that the question is therefore not appropriate for the site. Like pornography, I know SF&F when I see it.☺

Accusing people of lying is 'not nice', hence you shouldn't do it.

What "FAQ"?
SE sites don't even have a "FAQ" as such, and haven't since 2013 when the old "FAQ page" was replaced by the new "help centre" which persists to this day. Such comments look like language left over from over a decade ago, likely to be confusing to new users who look for anything on the site named "FAQ" and fail to find it.
Typing in scifi.stackexchange.com/faq redirects one to the tour page, so reasonable interpretations of the modern meaning of "site FAQ" could include either the help centre or the tour page (both of which are linked from the question-mark icon in the top bar).
There's also the faq tag here on meta, which comprises a loose collection of important meta discussions defining important things like site scope and policy on a variety of issues. This tag is maintained by moderators as and when we remember that it exists and bother to do anything about it (the current state of the tag is largely what it was after my overhaul in 2016, when as a newly elected moderator I went through many old meta posts to learn more about the workings and history of the site I'd just become responsible for moderating). Although site policy is often decided on meta, it's not necessarily reasonable to expect the faq tag to always contain an accurate and up-to-date of site policy.
What "definition of science fiction and fantasy"?
This site essentially operates on an "I know it when I see it" policy, backed up by some general meta posts from 2011 as well as new meta posts about specific works/franchises as and when necessary to iron out grey areas (the latter have been much less frequently needed in recent years). Some of the important meta posts from 2011 are the one(s) clarifying that site scope is essentially "speculative fiction" rather than the clunkier and perhaps more restrictive "science fiction and fantasy", and this much-cited list of criteria clarifying the desire to be inclusive and err on the side of counting things as on-topic if there's any reasonable way to argue that they are.
The last meta post linked above has the faq tag, so technically it could be said that our site's policy on what posts count as sufficiently SFFnal to be on-topic is "defined in the FAQ", but I think that's a massive stretch. Imagine being a new user and hearing that your question is off-topic because of a definition found "in the FAQ". You'd first have to figure out what's meant by FAQ in this context, which would require discovering an entirely separate Q&A site known as "meta" and then searching for "FAQ" in its tags list. Then you'd have to browse through twenty (or more in future) different meta discussions to figure out which of all those answers has some bearing on what science fiction and fantasy are (which it doesn't, actually - it doesn't attempt to define the genres themselves, only what should and shouldn't be permitted on this site). Before figuring all that out, you'd long ago have given up and quit.

TL;DR: it's perfectly fine to say "This question doesn't appear to be about science fiction or fantasy" and to vote to close as such, but "as defined in the FAQ" is at best confusing, at worst misleading. There's no attempt in the FAQ (under any possible interpretation of what's meant by "FAQ", a term that's been mostly retired on SE since 2013) to define what science fiction and fantasy are.

Gosh, if only someone had repeatedly asked you to create a fourth custom close reason precisely so we don't need to argue over the language

@Valorum Send your complaints to the Stack Overflow company, not your elected moderators. The moderators can't create more than 3 custom close reasons on network sites like this.

@IanCampbell - We were already told we could have one, but the CMs were, for reasons best understood by themselves (because I sure as hell couldn't work it out) wanting different wording.

@IanCampbell - Our own moderators don't seem interested in pushing the issue, despite a large positive vote in favour of doing so, and I've really lost interest in pushing them to push. What's hilarious is that the wording that was refused as the custom close reason is pretty much the same thing that we're writing over and over again as a self-written close reason

The site tour (which was linked in the comment you mentioned) doesn't actually provide a clear definition of Science Fiction and Fantasy. Instead, our community's understanding of what constitutes on-topic material is spread across several meta discussions. This makes it challenging to point newcomers to a single, comprehensive resource.
For example, we have various meta posts that delve into specific aspects of what's considered on-topic or off-topic works for our site:

Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)
Would non-horror Speculative Fiction be on-topic for this site?
What is and what isn't considered science fiction?
Does "Fantasy" include the supernatural? What about horror?
Are questions about alternate history on or off topic?
Are comic superheroes considered sci-fi?

Given this situation, it might be beneficial to create a centralized meta post that consolidates links to all our major discussions about what qualifies as on-topic sci-fi or fantasy work. This approach is similar to our existing meta post "What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?", which serves as a hub for various topicality discussions and is linked in the Help Center.
To make this information more accessible, we should consider adding a direct link to this proposed meta post in both the tour and the Help Center. The tour already includes links to several faq-tagged meta posts in the "Don't ask about..." section, so it would make sense to add a corresponding link in the "Ask about..." section as well.
These changes would provide clearer guidance to new users and make it easier for community members to reference our site's scope when addressing questions about potentially non-sci-fi/fantasy topics, which often come up in identification questions.
For potentially non-sci-fi/fantasy ID questions, I usually leave this comment, which focuses on adding on-topic details rather than referencing definitions:

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about a science fiction or fantasy work. But if you are looking to identify an on-topic work, please [edit] your question and share more details about its sci-fi or fantasy aspects so that we can better help you. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.


The question of what is, and isn't on-topic on Science Fiction and Fantasy SE was part of the basic core discussions that took place on SFF:Meta within the first few days of its announcement. The one/s you're probably going to be most interested in is/are...

What is and what isn't considered science fiction?

...as well as...

Is Fantasy in spec for this site?

Rather than link to multiple meta discussions extending over multiple pages, the appropriate action is to link people to the [FAQ] where they will find the following statements (I've bolded the important bits)

Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:

Plot, character, or setting explanations
Historical or societal context of a work
Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
Story identification
Franchise/series reading or viewing order


and

My question about the site isn't answered here
Check our community [FAQ], and more generally our meta-discussion site (please do not ask questions about the site on the main site).


Admittedly saying that the definition is directly included in the [FAQ] is probably a little bit clunky, and it's certainly a tautology to say that SFF:SE is only for SFF, but the alternative is to say...

This question doesn't appears to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy, as defined on our meta site in the following discussions with the scope which you can find at these nine locations; etc, etc, etc, etc, blah, blah, blah.

... or worse, we get to fight a running battle over what language to include in the FAQ about what is, and isn't science fiction.
